# Java ambiguous method name, despite different parameter type

Tags: java, junit, overloading

I'm receiving this error through Junit testing while trying to overload a method with a different parameter type.

The method getGame is ambiguous for the type ""

Here are the two methods

```
public Game getGame(Game x) {
    return null;    
}
public Game getGame(String p){
    return null;
}
```

Comment: You must be calling it with `null`. You have to cast it to one or the other. Hard to see why `getGame(Game x)` is needed.

Comment: Can you provide junit code where you are getting this error.

Comment: Yes I am calling it with null. You're right I don't actually need to overload was just overthinking it

Comment: Cast null appropriately.  (String) null or (Game) null to eliminate the error.

Comment: Have worked it out now thanks for the help!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  The way to say "thanks" is to vote up comments and answers that are helpful, and especially, select the answer that solves your issue (click the check mark).  In addition, selecting an answer shows everyone that the question has a solution (when hunting for questions to help with.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are calling with null you can cast it or assign it to a variable:

Casting:

```
getGame((Game) null);
```

Assigning to a variable:

```
Game game = null;
getGame(game);
```